# Java: Can't remove backslash when appending to a string

Tags: java

I'm creating a string representation of a file path. I'm working on a Windows machine.

The end result should look like this:

```
C:\Users\this_is_me\workarea\Myapp\myapp\props\
```

Instead it looks like this:

```
C:\Users\this_is_me\workarea\Myapp\myapp\\props\
```

The error is that second backslash before `props`. I think that this error is occurring because `\p` might be a regex expression?

Here is the code where I create the string:

```
private final static String APP_HOME = "\\workarea\\Myapp\\myapp\\";
private final static String PROPS_HOME = "\\props\\";

public static String getPropsPath() {
    String propsHome = null;
    String userHome = System.getProperty("user.home");
    propsHome = userHome + APP_HOME + PROPS_HOME;

    return propsHome;
}
```

I tried using a `StringBuilder` and I still get the same result.

Comment: Next time, I suggest that you look closely at your code before posting to SO.

Comment: I looked at it closely and I still couldn't see my mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the extra backslash after `APP_HOME`:

```
private final static String APP_HOME = "\\workarea\\Myapp\\myapp";
private final static String PROPS_HOME = "\\props\\";

propsHome = userHome + APP_HOME + PROPS_HOME;
System.out.println(propsHome);
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\this_is_me\workarea\Myapp\myapp\props\
```

Answer (score 2):

APP_HOME ends with \ and PROPS_HOME starts with \, so you get it twice.

If you really want to build paths this way, remove one these backslashes. But should also have a look at the File and Path classes, which are better suited for these kind of things.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like **APP_HOME** ends with backslash and **PROPS_HOME** starts with backslash, therefore you get double backlash as a result of concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Since the first letter of PROPS_HOME starts with \ and the end of APP_HOME is \ you get it twice,

propsHome = userHome + APP_HOME + PROPS_HOME.substring(1);

Comment: can somebody explain the downvote? i am removing the first \ and keeping the rest characters as is.

Comment: You have a perfectly valid answer. The downvote may be from a troll or someone who doesn't understand Java.

Comment: @SamTebbs33 thanks, new here so not really aware of situations which can cause down votes :)